# PhantomJS stops working in Gemini testing

Tags: testing, phantomjs, regression-testing, yandex, uitest

I'm getting exact same error discussed [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11526), when I'm running UI automation using [Gemini Testing](https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini) . The error start happening when the number of tests exceeded 100. Any pointer to fix this issue is really appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [sipayRT](https://github.com/sipayRT) from Gemini ...  he suggested me to try setting "suitesPerSession": 10 in gemini config. That seems fixed my issue.